# How to insert a Google Analytics code snippet into my code so that it does not violate the Content Security Policy?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-analytics, content-security-policy

I added the following CSP: (following the instructions from this page: https://www.bounteous.com/insights/2017/07/20/using-google-analytics-and-google-tag-manager-content-security-policy/)

script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com;

img-src https://www.google-analytics.com [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) https://stats.g.doubleclick.net;

connect-src https://www.google-analytics.com [www.google-analytics.com](http://www.google-analytics.com) https://stats.g.doubleclick.net

#### index.html:

```
<head>
   <script src="./googleAnalytics.js"></script>
</head>
```

#### googleAnalytics.js:

```
let ga_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxx"; // (id)
let ga_script = document.createElement("SCRIPT");

ga_script.type = "text/javascript";
ga_script.src = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=${ga_id}`;
let script2 = document.createElement("SCRIPT");

script2.type = "text/javascript";

script2.text = `
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', '${ga_id}');`;

document.head.appendChild(ga_script);
document.head.appendChild(script2);
```

#### serverj.js ### (I have another CSP within the helmet npm package)

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader(
    "Content-Security-Policy",
    "script-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com; img-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net; connect-src 'self' https://www.google-analytics.com www.google-analytics.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net;"
  );
  next();
});

app.use(helmet(
  ........
));
```

But it's still giving me CSP errors. I can't figure out what CSP to add or what I got wrong that it's not working. Does anyone see that I've implemented something wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you have been followed the wrong instructions. Also, you have not shown what exactly is being blocked in your case - you just need to add the blocked sources to the corresponding directives.

Anyway, if you do not use nonces, the [CSP for Google Analytics](http://csplite.com/csp/test31/) is:

```
connect-src www.google-analytics.com https://ampcid.google.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net;

img-src www.google-analytics.com https://www.google.com/ads/ga-audiences https://stats.g.doubleclick.net;

script-src 'self' google-analytics.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com www.google-analytics.com;
```

You do not need `'unsafe-inline'` in the `script-src` since you insert GA script as external `googleAnalytics.js` file that falls under `'self'`. You can check exactly your Google Analytics ID in the test linked above.

There can only be one problem - Google Analytics is tightly integrated with the Google Ads Conversion/Remarketing Tags, which use a geographic domains like `https://www.google.(com|fr|co.uk|...)/ads/` for loading Ads tracker.
Therefore, the geofence of the `www.google` domain depends on the IP of the visitor, but it is unrealistic to list all [Google geodomains](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_domaines_de_Google#Domaines_locaux_du_moteur_de_recherche_Google) (sorry, link is in French, but domain names are readable).
Therefore, blocking of such geo-domains will occasionally be observed. The good news is that GA's work is not affected by this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solved my problem. Only for some reason I still had to explicitly enter `"default-src": ["'self'"]` into helmet even though I have already set: `useDefaults: true` Without that, it gave me an error with connect-src

Comment: Yes, `useDefaults: true` should implicitly set `"default-src": ["'self'"]`. But explicitly initiating directives is a good solution. This will save you from surprises of unexpected Helmet package behavior.